# How to convert the result of a fitted curve from "cfit" to actual array data in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, curve-fitting, curve, data-fitting

I would like to fit a certain curve. My data is stored in "x" and "y2". To fit that curve, there are predefined functions like "fit".

My example:

```
x = [20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 200];
y = [4.229 2.514 1.714 1.143 0.8 0.629 0.514 0.4 0.349 0.057];
p_0 = 2*10^(-5);
y2 = 10.^(y/20)*p_0;

[xData,yData] = prepareCurveData(x,y2);
fit_type = 'pchipinterp';

[fitresult] = fit(xData,yData,ft);
```

The result "fitresult" is now stored in the MATLAB Workspace as a "1x1 cfit" object.
Is there any way to get an actual array out of *fitresult* with a array length that I can manually define? (e.g. MATLAB Workspace: fitresult: 1x3841 *double*)

Answer (score 1):

edit ur script:

```
fit_type = 'pchipinterp';
[fitresult] = fit(xData,yData,fit_type);
```

fitresult have two classes **Coefficients** and **Shape-preserving (pchip) interpolant**, in each one there is one component **p** and **fitresult(x)**
fitresult =

```
 Shape-preserving (pchip) interpolant:
   fitresult(x) = piecewise polynomial computed from p
 Coefficients:
   p = coefficient structure
```

to extract the results add those code lines to ur script (name is up to u):

```
1. piecewise_polynomial_computed_from_p = fitresult(x)      
2. coefficient_structure = fitresult.p
```

here coefficient_structure is a constructor:

```
coefficient_structure = 
      form: 'pp'
    breaks: [20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 200]
     coefs: [9x4 double]
    pieces: 9
     order: 4
       dim: 1
```

to extract results from it type for example :

```
Breaks = coefficient_structure.breaks
```

results is :

```
Breaks =
    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100   200
```

Comment: Your absolutely right, in my code there should be "fit_type" instead of "ft".

Comment: Thank you for the informations!!
But I how can i get the complete values from the *fitresult*? For example the values between 20 and 30 that connect the y-values between 4.229 and 2.514? 
Almost like i would like to plot the interpolated values such as plot(x_array_length_of_the_interpolated_values,interpolated_values).
can I calculated those values out of *coefficient_structure.breaks* and *coefficient_structure.coefs*?

Comment: I don't understand what u need exactly, but I guess : - 
figure(1)
plot(x, piecewise_polynomial_computed_from_p')
figure(2)
plot(y, piecewise_polynomial_computed_from_p')

highlight the fit function then press cntl+d or debugging the script and enter to the function ("fit") follow the script until the step of calculation of coefficient_structure.breaks and coefficient_structure.coefs elements to inspire from it.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I actually could get a pretty decent result in the curve fitting tool where as my fittype is 'exp2'. The equation and the coefficients can be printed out and plotted seperately. Therefore I got my data. :D

Comment: I’m happy to help.